# wordpress video custom post type

Tags: wordpress

сделал пост тайп, сделал категории но мне нужен чтобы каждый категория имее свое изабражение, и как вывести их в коде?
вот сам код

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );

function register_post_types(){

global $maflo_theme_options;

$video_permalink = ( strlen( $maflo_theme_options['video_permalink'] ) > 0 ) ? $maflo_theme_options['video_permalink'] : _x( 'video', 'video permalink slug', "maflo" );

register_post_type('videos', array(
    'label'  => null,
    'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'Videos',
        'singular_name'      => 'Video',
        'add_new'            => 'Add Video',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add Video',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Video',
        'new_item'           => 'New Video',
        'view_item'          => 'View Video',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Video',
        'menu_name'          => 'Video',
        'featured_image'     => 'Video Image',
        'set_featured_image' => 'Add Video Image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Delete Video Image',
    ),
    'description'         => 'Maflo Custom Video',
    'public'              => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'supports'            => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies'          => array(),
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
    'rewrite'         => array(
        'slug'       => untrailingslashit( $video_permalink ),
        'with_front'  => false,
        'feeds'     => true,
        'ep_mask'       => EP_PERMALINK
    ),
    'query_var'           => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
) );


}

add_action( 'init', 'video_category' );

function video_category() {

global $maflo_theme_options;

$video_taxonomy_permalink = ( strlen( $maflo_theme_options['video_category_permalink'] ) > 0 ) ? $maflo_theme_options['video_category_permalink'] : _x( 'video-category', 'video category permalink slug', "maflo" );

register_taxonomy(
    'video_category',
    'videos',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Category' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'query_var' => 'true',
        'rewrite'      => array(
            'slug'      => $video_taxonomy_permalink,
            'with_front'     => false,
            'hierarchical'  => true
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
);
}
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7686/miniatyury-dlya-elemetov-taksonomij.html

Comment: Спасибо большое получилься